# How to position 'Sign here' tag using Anchor text?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Rest API for creating envelope with anchor text based 'Sign here ' tab positioning. When I set anchorXOffset value as zero the tab is positioned in between the anchor text. For example my Anchor text is 'Mr A Sign here:' . The Sign here tab overlaps the Anchor string. I read that the X Offset is offset from end of the anchor text, however behaviour is not same
Please let me know whether my understanding is incorrect
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [REST API documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm), this is expected behavior:

> The bottom-left of the anchorString is equivalent to
>   position (0,0), and the bottom-left of the Tab graphic is placed
>   relative to that.

When tagging using anchor strings within the DocuSign console the behavior is as you describe (tag appears at the end of the anchor string) perhaps this is where the confusion arose.